# Map inner list (List(String) in List) to inner case class gives "Object does not take parameters" error

Tags: scala

Mapping List of List to inner case class gives error Object does not take parameters

My List data:

```
val lstEmpAddrRec = List( List("John", "Developer", List("123 Main St", "Chicago")), 
                          List("Kevin", "Architect", List("444 Madrid Ln", "Los Angeles")))
```

I am mapping the list into 2 case classes:

```
case class clsAddr(addr1: String, city: String)
case class clsEmp(name: String, jobDesc: String, addr: clsAddr)


lstEmpAddrRec.map(x => clsEmp(x(0).toString, x(1).toString, clsAddr(x(2)(0), x(2)(1))
    )).foreach(println)
```

I am getting below error:

```
error: Object does not take parameters
lstEmpAddrRec.map(x => clsEmp(x(0).toString, x(1).toString, clsAddr(x(2)(0), x(2)(1))
```

Outer object (clsEmp) mapping looks good, but inner object (clsAddr) doesn't accept the conversion.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of problems here...

Firstly, although I'm being a tad pedantic, you do not have *inner* or *outer* classes. An *inner* class is one defined as a member of another, *outer* class, like this:

```
class Outer {
  class Inner {
    // ...
  }
}
```

That's not what you have here.

Secondly, if you look at the type of `lstEmpAddrRec`, it is a `List` of a `List` of heterogenous objects (a `String`, a `String` and a `List[String]`). As a result its type is: `List[List[java.io.Serializable]]` (as `java.io.Serializable` is the only trait in common to `String` and `List[String]`). In general, creating lists of such objects probably isn't what you intended.

Thirdly, when you apply `map` to `lstEmpAddrRec`, `x` will have the type `List[java.io.Serializable]`, which does not have members that match the argument types expected of your case classes or allow you to use expressions such as `x(2)(0)` as there is no such method that belongs to a list of `Serializable`.

I think what you want is more like this (I've switched to a `Vector` from a `List`, because the `.appy(Int)` method of a `List` isn't particularly efficient):

```
case class clsAddr(addr1: String, city: String)

case class clsEmp(name: String, jobDesc: String, addr: clsAddr)

case class Data(name: String, function: String, address: Vector[String])

val lstEmpAddrRec = List(Data("John", "Developer", Vector("123 Main St", "Chicago")),
Data("Kevin", "Architect", Vector("444 Madrid Ln", "Los Angeles")))

val listEmp = lstEmpAddrRec.map {
  x =>
  clsEmp(x.name, x.function, clsAddr(x.address(0), x.address(1)))
}
```

Here, `lstEmpAddrRec` is a `List[Data]`, and `x` is `Data` instance, which keeps things nice and simple.

Alternatively, you could use a *tuple* instead of the `Data` case class, like this:

```
case class clsAddr(addr1: String, city: String)

case class clsEmp(name: String, jobDesc: String, addr: clsAddr)

val lstEmpAddrRec = List(("John", "Developer", Vector("123 Main St", "Chicago")),
("Kevin", "Architect", Vector("444 Madrid Ln", "Los Angeles")))

val listEmp = lstEmpAddrRec.map {
  x =>
  clsEmp(x._1, x._2, clsAddr(x._3(0), x._3(1)))
}
```

In this case, `lstEmpAddrRec` is a `List[(String, String, Vector[String])]`, and `x` is `(String, String, Vector[String])` (which is a tuple, as indicated by the parentheses at either end of the expression).

**UPDATE**: Added the following clarification based upon @KiranM's comment below.

The problem is not a list of lists, as such. The primary problem is that you have two different types of value in one of the lists. Take this data record:

```
List("John", "Developer", List("123 Main St", "Chicago"))
```

The members of the (first) list are: a `String` (`"John"`); another `String` (`"Developer"`); and a `List[String]` (`List["123 Main St", "Chicago"]`).

So what is the type of this list? To answer this, the *Scala* compiler needs to consider what the members have in common in terms of their types. So what do `String` and `List[String]` have in common? Well, they're both (ultimately) descended from `AnyRef`. However, they also both implement the `java.io.Serializable` trait/interface (which allows instances to be serialized and deserialized to/from data streams). Hence, the *Scala* compiler reasons that this is a list of `Serializable`. i.e. `List[Serializable]`. You can verify this by opening the *Scala REPL* and typing this expression in, as follows:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_151).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> List("John", "Developer", List("123 Main St", "Chicago"))
res0: List[java.io.Serializable] = List(John, Developer, List(123 Main St, Chicago))
```

So, when you attempt to convert this record into a `clsEmp` instance in the `map` function, you take a `List[Serializable]` (the inferred type of `x` in your code) with three members and attempt to use it as follows:

```
clsEmp(x(0).toString, x(1).toString, clsAddr(x(2)(0), x(2)(1)))
```

So let's break this down.

The first argument to the `clsEmp` constructor is `x(0).toString` and must have type `String`. `x` is a `List[Serializable]`, so `x(0)` is the first element in the list, and (so far as the compiler can tell) it has type `Serializable` with the value `"John"`. (Although the actual type of `x(0)`is `String`, the compiler isn't smart enough to know that.) You then convert this value to a `String` via the `.toString` method. Since `x(0)` actually is a `String`, its `toString` method just returns the value `"John"` as a `String`. So we're good.

Note that if you hadn't added the `.toString` conversion, you would have received an argument type error, because you would have been assigning a `Serializable` to a `String`. You can verify this in the *REPL* as follows:

```
scala> val x = List("John", "Developer", List("123 Main St", "Chicago"))
x: List[java.io.Serializable] = List(John, Developer, List(123 Main St, Chicago))

scala> x(0)
res0: java.io.Serializable = John

scala> val s: String = x(0)
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.io.Serializable
 required: String
       val s: String = x(0)
                        ^

scala> val s: String = x(0).toString
s: String = John
```

In exactly the same manner, the second argument to the constructor, `x(1).toString` assigns the `String` `"Developer"` to the `clsEmp` member `jobDesc`.

I'll just mention here that, if you know that the first two arguments have type `String`, it is safer if you convert the values to `String`s explicitly, so that you get a run-time cast conversion exception if the values are not actually of that type. This is because literally everything has a valid `.toString` method, which can mask type errors. With explicit casts, the code now looks like this:

```
clsEmp(x(0).asInstanceOf[String], x(1).asInstanceOf[String], clsAddr(x(2)(0), x(2)(1)))
```

But we still haven't yet dealt with the errors creating the `clsAddr` instance. Now, the chickens really start coming home to roost...

So let's focus upon just the `clsAddr` constructor call:

```
clsAddr(x(2)(0), x(2)(1))
```

So, the first argument must be a `String`, yet we have passed it `x(2)(0)`. When *Scala* evaluates this, it processes the first set of parentheses, which is the expression `x(2)`. So far, so good, this is a `Serializable`. It now attempts to apply the second set of parentheses to the `Serializable` instance. But a `Serializable` has no `.apply(Int)` method, nor is there any function in scope that can implicitly convert it to something that has. Again, you can verify this in the *REPL*:

```
scala> val x = List("John", "Developer", List("123 Main St", "Chicago"))
x: List[java.io.Serializable] = List(John, Developer, List(123 Main St, Chicago))

scala> x(2)
res0: java.io.Serializable = List(123 Main St, Chicago)

scala> x(2)(0)
<console>:13: error: java.io.Serializable does not take parameters
   x(2)(0)
       ^
```

The exact same problem occurs with the second `clsAddr` constructor argument.

Can we fix this? Sure: we can explicitly convert the `x(2)` expression to a `List[String]`, before applying the second set of parentheses, as follows:

```
clsAddr(x(2).asInstanceOf[List[String]](0), x(2).asInstanceOf[List[String]](1))
```

You can verify this with the *REPL* too:

```
scala> case class clsAddr(addr1: String, city: String)
defined class clsAddr

scala> val x = List("John", "Developer", List("123 Main St", "Chicago"))
x: List[java.io.Serializable] = List(John, Developer, List(123 Main St, Chicago))

scala> clsAddr(x(2).asInstanceOf[List[String]](0), x(2).asInstanceOf[List[String]](1))
res0: clsAddr = clsAddr(123 Main St,Chicago)
```

So, we can get your original code to work by explicitly converting the elements of the list to the appropriate types, as demonstrated by the following *Scala REPL* session:

```
scala> case class clsAddr(addr1: String, city: String)
defined class clsAddr

scala> case class clsEmp(name: String, jobDesc: String, addr: clsAddr)
defined class clsEmp

scala> val lstEmpAddrRec = List( List("John", "Developer", List("123 Main St", "Chicago")),
     | List("Kevin", "Architect", List("444 Madrid Ln", "Los Angeles")))
lstEmpAddrRec: List[List[java.io.Serializable]] = List(List(John, Developer, List(123 Main St, Chicago)), List(Kevin, Architect, List(444 Madrid Ln, Los Angeles)))

scala> lstEmpAddrRec.map(x => clsEmp(x(0).asInstanceOf[String], x(1).asInstanceOf[String],
     | clsAddr(x(2).asInstanceOf[List[String]](0), x(2).asInstanceOf[List[String]](1)))).foreach(println)
clsEmp(John,Developer,clsAddr(123 Main St,Chicago))
clsEmp(Kevin,Architect,clsAddr(444 Madrid Ln,Los Angeles))
```

OK, so we've got it to work. But I think you'll agree that it looks very fugly. In general, whenever you have to explicitly cast values, you have a very *bad smell* in your code. The root cause is that you have put fundamentally different types of value (`String` and `List[String]`) into the same `List`. Hence my suggestions to change how your data is structured by either using a *tuple* or a *case class*.

One other alternative that you might consider is to just use a flat list to represent each record, as follows:

```
scala> case class clsAddr(addr1: String, city: String)
defined class clsAddr

scala> case class clsEmp(name: String, jobDesc: String, addr: clsAddr)
defined class clsEmp

scala> val lstEmpAddrRec = List( List("John", "Developer", "123 Main St", "Chicago"),
     | List("Kevin", "Architect", "444 Madrid Ln", "Los Angeles"))
lstEmpAddrRec: List[List[String]] = List(List(John, Developer, 123 Main St, Chicago), List(Kevin, Architect, 444 Madrid Ln, Los Angeles))

scala> lstEmpAddrRec.map(x => clsEmp(x(0), x(1), clsAddr(x(2), x(3)))).foreach(println)
clsEmp(John,Developer,clsAddr(123 Main St,Chicago))
clsEmp(Kevin,Architect,clsAddr(444 Madrid Ln,Los Angeles))
```

Here, no explicit casting is required, and the expression does what you expect. This is because `x` is now just a regular `List[String]` (and `lstEmpAddrRec` is now a `List[List[String]]`).

One final note on performance: if you're going to use the `.apply(Int)` method to retrieve values from the collection, bear in mind that, for a `List`, it must process every value in the list up to the index sought. By contrast, a `Vector` (or an `Array`) is organized to execute `.apply(Int)` in constant time.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I used case-class for simplicity. I don't think it makes much difference in using real class & case-classes. And I agree it makes more sense to use List of tuples as in your case#2 rather than List of Lists and it works for list of tuples. And using Vectors or Lists shouldn't make difference.

Comment: @KiranM Was there part of your question that I didn't answer?

Comment: Thanks Mike. Actually we are modifying the data to work for our code. But I still didn't fully understand (Serializable stuff) why I get error with inner case class List of Lists, but not with outer case class. I would need to dig more into it.

Comment: @KiranM I've added some further explanation that takes you through, step-by-step, the problems with your original code. If there's anything you still don't understand, let me know...